# vi Specification

Tags: original-vi

I am looking to polish up Open Watcom's Text Editor's vi mode (it's open source), but I don't have expert experience with vi.  Is there a de facto standard or formal specification for how vi's features should behave?

Comment: Here is a link to vi's POSIX specifications: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such standard is the [POSIX standard for vi](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) and [for ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ex.html) which are too long to include here.

Comment: Note, it contains a separate description on all the ex commands: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ex.html